# Can I specify a keyspace for a SingleOrDefault<string>() call without hardcoding it?

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I know that for a typical `_mapper.SingleOrDefault<SomeType>(new Cql("?", ex))` call I can create a mapping for SomeType and specify a keybase. Right now I would like to do:

```
var result = _mapper.SingleOrDefault<string>(new Cql("select json * from tablename where varname=?", arg));
```

or

```
var result = CassandraRetryHelper.SingleWithRemoteRetryAsync<string>(new Cql("select json * from tablename where varname=?", arg), _mapper);
```

Both of these give the desired result if I hardcode the keyspace name before the table name, but I would like to instead specify the keyspace beforehand like you can do with the first example. Is there any way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Define "*keybase*" and "*keyspace*"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, keybase is an unrelated variable. @TheGeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the mapper at all for that use case? If you just want to run a query without any mapping involved you can just use `session.ExecuteAsync(query)`.

In any case, try setting the keyspace at the builder level, i.e., `builder.WithDefaultKeyspace()` when building the cluster / session objects.

If you use multiple keyspaces then I'm afraid you will have to do something like `$"select json * from {keyspace}.tablename where varname=?"`. With this approach you will not be using query parameters which get validated by C* so make sure to sanitize the `keyspace` variable.